# AlterField shows the error `Duplicate key name`

Tags: python, mysql, django

In my migration file, there is the `AlterField` like this

```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='historicalglobalparam',
        name='history_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(db_index=True),
    ),
```

my table `historicalglobalparam` has `history_date` column

When appling this

`$python manage.py migrate`

The error appears

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1061, "Duplicate key name 'shared_models_historicalglobalparam_history_date_26e0c543'")`

However there comes error like this.

I wonder it's `AlterField` not `AddField`

Why this erorr comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might already have an index on that field. Try and remove that index like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048179/7088596) suggests